# Calling public class method in another class as a plugin in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

i have implemented a (track)class which works fine as standalone, but when i am trying to integrate it in another project using inheritance it gives me error.
snippet as below

```
 //file ctrack.hpp

    class ctrack {
    public:
        explicit ctrack(int mxc);
    
        void register_Object(int cX, int cY);
    
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>> update(std::vector<std::vector<int>> boxes);
    
        std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> path_keeper;
    private:
         
        std::map<int, int> disappeared;
    };
```

calling class snp.hpp

```
//file snp.hpp
#include "ctrack.h"

    class snp : public ctrack, public obsd
    {
    public:
    void detect();
    };
```

Now when i try to call the update function in snp.cpp

```
//fiel snp.cpp
void snp::detect(ushort data)
{   
    
    static std::vector<cv::Rect2d> boxes; 
    
   snp->update(boxes);//calling method from ctrack class

}
```

i have tried other methods also like
creating object of ctrack class inside the detect class and calling the update method.

error ex 1)  error: expected primary-expression before ‘->’ token
auto objects =  ctrack->update(boxes);
2) error: no matching function for call to ‘snp::update(std::vector<cv::Rect_ >&)’
auto objects = update(boxes);

but i am missing the basics.

please help, how can i easily call the method update from ctrack class
inside detect method inside snp class

much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `ctrack` doesn't seem to have any member function called `detect`.  Did you mean to use `update` in your code, which matches your actual error message?

Comment: @StephenNewell         I have corrected the statement, i am trying to call update method of ctrack class inside detect method of snp class.

Comment: `snp->update(boxes);` - should this simply be `update(boxes);`?

Comment: i have tried this as well calling it directly as    objects=update(boxes) ; it gives me error    error: no matching function for call to ‘snp::update(std::vector<cv::Rect_<double> >&)’
         auto objects = update(boxes);

Comment: `boxes` of type `std::vector<cv::Rect_<double>>` does not match the argument type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`